# How can I multiply the matrices to get to a certain location (T * R * S)

Tags: opengl, matrix, transform, homogenous-transformation

I have this picture, I need to get from right's position house to left's position house:[image]

Well, in OpenGL it is simple,

```
    glTranslated(6,0,0);
    glRotated(30, 0, 0, 1);
    glScaled(2, 2, 0);
```

But I am trying to understand how it actually works 'behind the scenes'.
Do I take a point, lets say the left bottom one, and work from there?

For example:

v1 = (0,1,0,1)
and first matrix would be the translation one so I multiply it by
the translation matrix where x = 6, y = 0, z = 0. and get a new point which is 
v2 = (6,1,0,1) and continue from there with scale and rotation matrix?

**Question:** What is the homogenous matrix that I will need to do that?

I guess it will be just multiplying T R S matrices in that order and it will produce me that matrix I need..

Answer (score 1):

Matrix multiplication is not commutative. That's a fancy way of saying that a translation followed by a rotation isn't the same as rotation followed by a translation. If you work through an example you'll quickly get the idea.

Now there are two conventions you can use, pre-multiply or post-multiply. Most graphics systems use the less intuitive convention, so that the operation applied last is in fact applied first. That makes it easier to deal with hierarchical systems that have translates high up in the hierarchy which you don't want to feed into rotations, creating big crankshaft moves. That does make it a bit more difficult to work out what happens when programming a sequence of operations by hand. Work backwards, and apply the rotations last is the general rule.

Comment: Thx Malcolm. very detailed

Answer (score 1):

What Malcom McLean said is true. I just thought I would mention that TRS *is* the matrix that you need, it is just that you need to multiply the matrices first before applying them to vertices e.g. TRS*v, which is the reverse of doing S*(R*(T*v)), which is what you were talking about doing by translating, then rotating, then scaling a point. **TLDR; transformations combined into a single matrix are applied in the reverse order of their multiplication. e.g. TRS*v => scale, rotate, then translate v.**